# How much of an asset is Ulfric Stormcloack?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls

In Skyrim you have the choice of siding with the Imperials or the Stormcloaks. Now, obviously the Thalmor has made the Empire it's puppet after the White-Gold Concordat however after infiltrating the embassy in one of the journals it talks about Ulfric Stormcloack being an asset.

The Thalmor want the Civil War in Skyrim to continue because it weakens the Empire and allows the Thalmor to finish them off one day, so obviously I was to s*** on the Thalmor's plans and put an end to the war (before dealing with Alduin).

I normally side with the empire because of the Blades but the Blades in Skyrim are all but gone (with me being able to restore them) but that Concordat sours things for me so my other option is to side with the Stormcloaks but Ulfric Stormcloack being an asset worries me a bit.

So I am wondering then, the Thalmor call Ulfric an asset, how much of one is he? Is he a sleeper agent and is purposely working with them or is he unaware that the indecisive civil is playing into the Thalmor's plans

Comment: I think Ulfric is an asset because as long as both he and the Emperor are alive, the civil war will continue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**He isn't an asset in the strict sense of the word**

He's valuable to the Dominion as long as he is a thorn in the Empire's side.  Remember that Ulfric's political views are that "Skyrim should be for the Nord" to the point where some of his stances border on racism.  As long as he is brewing civil war, the Empire is weakened and will either permit the Dominion to operate within its borders or may actually need to seek their help.

Ulfric *actually succeeding* is probably not in the Aldmeri's plans as he'll undoubtably back out of the White-Gold Concordat and try to rid the lands of foreigners (including them).

This is actually outlined in the note you find, including the fact that Ulfric is an "asset" even though they haven't contacted him yet and if they are using him - it is behind the scenes without his knowledge:

> Operational Notes: *Direct contact remains a possibility (under extreme circumstances)*, but in general the asset should be considered dormant. As long as the civil war proceeds in its current indecisive fashion, *we should remain hands-off*. The incident at Helgen is an example where an exception had to be made - obviously Ulfric's death would have dramatically increased the chance of an Imperial victory and thus harmed our overall position in Skyrim. (NOTE: The coincidental intervention of the dragon at Helgen is still under scrutiny. The obvious conclusion is that whoever is behind the dragons also has an interest in the continuation of the war, but we should not assume therefore that their goals align with our own.) *A Stormcloak victory is also to be avoided, however, so even indirect aid to the Stormcloaks must be carefully managed.*

Emphasis mine.  Everyone is a potential asset (dormant in this case meaning "no direct activity") to the Thalmor, whether they know it or not.  It is just their way of making inventory.